# Small files in Hadoop vs Shuffle Time - Tunning

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

What would be the better way to reduce & tune shuffle time when handling so many small files?

Due to some other limitations + requirement, I cannot reduce number of small files and I know the problem with handling small files. But I would like to know what other options are still available here in order to reduce shuffle time for a given MapReduce job?

For a single MapReduce job, I get something like below:

```
Average Map Time    33sec
Average Reduce Time 10sec
Average Shuffle Time    1hrs, 10mins, 18sec
Average Merge Time  2sec
```

I would like to know is there any other options I can try to reduce this shuffle time?

For the above data, my # of mapper was: 14778

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple small files you can use all those small files and submit them to one single mapper by using MultipleInputs format in your driver. Something like below :

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]),TextInputFormat.class,CounterMapper.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[1]),TextInputFormat.class,CountertwoMapper.class);
```

Also you can implement custom comparator to reduce the load of shuffle.

Comment: The problem I have is, each file is a binary file in a specific format, so I need to take each file separately to process it. Let me explain little bit more:

Inputs:
    /staging/2015/04/17/a.abc
    /staging/2015/04/17/b.abc
    /staging/2015/04/17/c.abc


Output:
   /parsed/2015/04/17/a.parsed
    /parsed/2015/04/17/b.parsed
    /parsed/2015/04/17/b.parsed

So each file with extension .abc need to be parsed and output to another location with a readable format (tsv).


About the custom comparator, could you please explain a little bit how it will help reducing shuffle time?